# PayPal accept credit cards directly on website

Tags: php, paypal, credit-card

I have got paypal payments integrated with my website, but i want to accept credit cards directly on my website without redirecting to PayPal site.

I heard that i need PayPal pro account, is it true?
Will it work outsite US? It will be probably hosted in Germany or Poland, is it any obstacle? PayPal account is probably registered in Germany.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

PayPal Payment PRO is available only for US,UK and CA.
Unfortunately, for Germany PRO is not supported.Yes, you need PRO acccount to accept direct credit cards. You just need a business PRO account.

Comment: And to accept credit cards directly on my site I need PayPal Payment PRO? And one more question. When i will move my website to production server do I need any special type of PayPal account to accept normal payments or free account is enough?